# VBA save word document as pdf from excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word, mailmerge

I have seen lots of people asking this question, but I cannot get it to work.

Background - I am creating a mail merge, from excel into a WORD template, which I then need to save as a PDF. My VBA code is in excel - and ideally needs to stay there. Mail merge is working, creating and saving the word documents as expected, but I cannot save as PDF.

My code to create the mail merge:

```
'Declare Some Variable
Dim FTR As String
Dim cDir As String
Dim r As Long
Dim ThisFileName As String
Dim bCreatedWordInstance As Boolean


'Set Up WORD object
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object

On Error Resume Next

    bCreatedWordInstance = False
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If objWord Is Nothing Then
        Err.Clear
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        bCreatedWordInstance = True
    End If
    If objWord Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not start Word"
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub
    End If
    objWord.Visible = True

    'Open Word Template
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\MailMergeTest\MAILMERGE TEMPLATE.dotx")

    objWord.Activate


' Let Word trap the errors
On Error GoTo 0

' Set to True if you want to see the Word Doc flash past during construction
objWord.Visible = False


' Setup filenames
Const WTempName = "MAILMERGE TEMPLATE.dotx" '
Dim NewFileName As String


' Setup directories
cDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" 'Change if appropriate
ThisFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name




lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Merge the data
With objDoc
With .MailMerge
.OpenDataSource Name:=cDir + ThisFileName, sqlstatement:="SELECT *  FROM `Sheet1$`"   ' Set this as required


For r = 1 To lastrow
    If Cells(r, 12).Value = "FTR Generated Already" Then GoTo nextrow
    FTR = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3).Value

        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
            With .DataSource
                .FirstRecord = r - 1
                .LastRecord = r - 1
                .ActiveRecord = r - 1
            End With
        .Execute Pause:=False

    ' Save new file
    NewFileName = "MAILMERGE TEST - " & FTR & ".docx"
    NewFileNamePDF = "MAILMERGE TEST - " & FTR & ".pdf"
    objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs cDir + NewFileName

    ' ***** SAVE AS PDF CODE HERE



 GoTo nextrow


0:
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Cells(r, 12).Value = "FTR Generated Already"

nextrow:

        Next r
    End With
    End With
    ' Close the New Mail Merged Document
            If bCreatedWordInstance Then
                objWord.Quit
            End If

    ' Close the Mail Merge Main Document
    objDoc.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Set objDoc = Nothing
```

I have tried the following:

```
objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=cDir & NewFileNamePDF, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
```

...this comes up with an error message saying 'Invalid procedure call or argument'.

Also tried:

```
objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 cDir + NewFileNamePDF, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
```

.. which exports a file, but it cannot be opened as a PDF.

Can anyone help out here?

Thank you in advance for your advice

Lee

Comment: Based on the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat), `ExportAsFixedFormat`should be working. What are the declaration of objDoc and objWord?

Comment: When run from Word, both code seems to be working on my computer.

Comment: If you are latebinding with word then try this `objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=cDir & NewFileNamePDF, ExportFormat:=17`

Comment: As indicated in a couple of other comments you don't include enough information to be sure what the problem is. IF you project does not have a reference to the Word object library then you need to use the approach proposed by Siddharth Rout because your code cannot use the `wd` enumerations. Although in that case I would expect an error earlier in the code. If this approach does not help: You provide no information about the content of the variables used for the file path. Check the entire path being provided as the new file name and show us what that is.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I have added some more of my code. Hopefully, this will shed extra light. I have tried the suggestion from Siddharth Rout, which creates a file, but it does not contain the mail merged data.

Comment: @LMORSE Instead of reinventing the wheel, see, for example, *Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** threads at http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html & http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/163017-Word-Mailmerge-Tips-amp-Tricks